# How Cassandra Cluster - Seed Provider Works?

Tags: database, cassandra, rhel, cassandra-2.0

I have a doubt on the cassandra seed_provider assignment. In my environment, there are 3 cassandra nodes required to setup as cluster. How should I define it in the cassandra.yaml? I'm confused since most of the tutorials gave different answers.

Example:
Host A - 192.168.1.1
Host B - 192.168.1.2
Host C - 192.168.1.3

The following is my current setup for Host A, is it correct?

What about the configuration for Host B & Host C?

```
# any class that implements the SeedProvider interface and has a
# constructor that takes a Map<String, String> of parameters will do.
seed_provider:
    # Addresses of hosts that are deemed contact points. 
    # Cassandra nodes use this list of hosts to find each other and learn
    # the topology of the ring.  You must change this if you are running
    # multiple nodes!
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          # seeds is actually a comma-delimited list of addresses.
          # Ex: "<ip1>,<ip2>,<ip3>"
          - seeds: "192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2,192.168.1.3"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For starters, you should not need to change the `class_name` of the `seed_provider`.  AFAIK, there is only one that ships with Cassandra.  It was defined to be "pluggable," to allow for custom seed providers to be written.

For `seeds`, I don't recommend designating every node in the seed list.  If there are only 3 nodes, then **just provide 1 or 2**.  Seed nodes do not bootstrap data, and require a `repair` to get consistent upon replacement.  This can make node adds difficult.

But as far as I see, your current config will work.  I would just build the seed list with a max of 2 nodes.

Just remember, that there are two main requirements for the `seed_list`:

- If you are starting the first node in the cluster, its IP must be in the `seed_list`.
- At least one of the nodes must be running.

> Do you mind further explain on what's the impact if I proceed to add all 3 nodes in the seed list? What are the reasons that you will only choose to add 1 or 2 nodes in seed list?

Sure, it all goes back to this:

> Seed nodes do not bootstrap data

Therefore, designating all 3 nodes in the `seed_list` on all 3 nodes allows for the following problems:

- If node A is started and data is written to it *before* nodes B or C are joined to the cluster, that data will *not* stream to the nodes B or C.
- If in the future, node A fails and is replaced, data will not stream to the replacement node.

In these cases, a `nodetool repair` will need to be run to get the initial data on to the newly added node.

Comment: means the best practice is to set Host B, and Host C as the seeds?
So I just have to apply the configuration of 
- seeds: "192.168.1.2,192.168.1.3" 
across all 3 A,B & C nodes?

Comment: @BlackHat That should be fine, as long as B or C is the first node started.

Comment: Do you mind further explain on what's the impact if I proceed to add all 3 nodes in the seed list? What are the reasons that you will only choose to add 1 or 2 nodes in seed list?